# Check if an integer is in a jsonb list

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to write a native query in JPA. I want to verify if an element exists in a `jsonb` column. However, I'm getting the error `integer <@ jsonb`.

**This is my query:**

```
@Query(
        value = "SELECT u FROM user u WHERE (u.depNum = ?1 and superAdmin = true " +
            "       and ?2 <@ (u.listUsers)) ",
        nativeQuery = true

    )
    public List<EbUser> selectSuperAdmin(Integer depNum, Integer userNum);
```

The error happens here: `?2 <@ (u.listUsers)`. How can I verify that `listUsers` contains the `userNum` or how can I convert the `userNum` to `jsonb` in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the conversion in PostgreSQL.

```
and to_jsonb(ARRAY[?2]) <@ (u.listUsers))
```

as long as JPA doesn't interfere with passing this construct into PostgreSQL, I have not tested that part.